# fork()-parent ignores execv() of an except script

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-12.04

The following code calls an except script which copies an file via ftp to a server.

```
int status;
int child_pnr;  

if((child_pnr = fork())==0)
{
    printf("Childnr %i\n",child_pnr);
    execv("/home/..../ftptest.exp",NULL);

}
else if (child_pnr > 0)
{
    printf("Parent... childnr %i generated\n",child_pnr);
    sleep(7);
}
else
    perror("fork() error");
```

As execv() will terminate after execution I spawned a childprocess for this function. Why is the ftptest.exp interupted from parent if I don't have the sleep(7)....

Comment: Just to clarify: `execv` (or any of the `exec` family of function) will not terminate after execution. Actually `execv` _replaces_ the child process with the process in the called program, and `execv` will never return (unless there is an error executing the program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "interrupted", I presume you mean that the parent does not wait for the child to complete the operation before doing whatever it does next?

The parent and the child will run in parallel after the fork. If you want the parent to "hang" until the child is done then you need to `wait` for it.

See `man wait` and search for fork examples on the internet.